# Why would console display different received string than message box in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient, tcpserver

This is a follow up to my previous question. But it appears that for a reason I don't understand, the os is interpreting a received string differently than a message box is. This is apparent as when using message box.show function, it shows the correct string that was received. But the if then statement, the code for if the string equals what it does equal does not execute, and also the same string comes across as only system.byte it does not show in the console.

Here is the code:

```
SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIP.Text, 8001); // receive the IP to listen from and port number for server.

        MessageBox.Show("Connected");

        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        MessageBox.Show("Listening for information......");

        byte[] bb = new byte[100];
        int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(bb));

        string atk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);
        MessageBox.Show("Received Command " + atk);

        if (atk == "g")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("working");
            Search.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm leaving out the actual background worker code is it works ok in other implementations.

I am wondering why this may be? Thanks.

Comment: Why use two different methods to convert a byte array to a string?  Clearly the ```Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);``` is doing what you expect and ```Convert.ToString(bb)``` is not.  Why not use the one that does what you want in both cases?

Comment: The Console.Write makes no sense but should not have any impact here. Maybe you just remove the for loop with the Console.WriteLine from the example code. It just distracts. Have you actually checked the content of the atk variable? Maybe it contains whitespaces or something like that. You won't see that in a Messagebox.

Comment: Try changing  "string atk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);" to "string atk = (Convert.ToString(bb))". They should be the same after that change.

Comment: That what I was saying. When using a message box the string shows we hat it should, but when using console.writeline the string does not show ad well the of the. Statement does not execute either way.

Comment: I wi give that a shot, thanks very much.

Comment: Convert.ToString for something other then base types will fall through to the ToString method of the given type. And in most cases where there isn't a specific ToString implementation you get the typename. So here "System.Byte". For converting bytes to string use an encoding. A certain byte is never a certain character when you don't specify an encoding like you already do.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you don't have it in a "while" loop or something but never mind that...
please try this:

```
byte[] bb = new byte[100];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb.AsSpan(0, k ));
Console.WriteLine($"Data Received: {data}");//test

//if you want your check
//this will not work if your incoming data contains white space or other bytes that were converted.

if (data == "g" ||data.Contains("g"))//the .Contains can solve that prob, but a mix of letters containing "g" will trigger it
    {
        MessageBox.Show("working");
        Search.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

if your still having trouble please debug your incoming bytes and sent one.

make sure your not sending other bytes other the the "g" that you have send, if you use a different conversion method it might add additional bytes.
Consider checking your sent and received bytes!